# Weird missing record issue with SOQL query

Tags: soql, rest-api, api

Can someone help me understand why this query is returning 1 less record than expected when a Date custom field (Due_Date__c) is included in the SELECT clause? As you can see in the screenshot, it's returning 180 of 181 records. It is not sending a nextRecordsUrl for a queryMore, and with only 181 records, there's not really a reason it would. It's just returning one less record than it says it will.

SELECT Id, Due_Date__c FROM Case WHERE MHHE_Mobile_Sync_Flag__c = true[image]

If I remove the Due_Date__c field, I get 181 of 181 returned, as expected:

[image]

Is there any logical reason this would happen?

Comment: is the output above from workbench?  what happens if you execute the query in developer console?

Comment: The output shown here is from Workbench for illustration, yes. The issue I'm having is in a custom iOS/Obj-C app, and I get the same result in SoqlXplorer. The user in question doesn't have access to the developer console, and the query with an Admin account seems to just be timing out in the dev console.

Answer (score 1):

You could try comparing the Ids from both results to find the one record that is not coming back when you get 180 of 181 records returned.

Once you know the record Id, try doing a specific query for just that record. E.g.

```
SELECT Id, Due_Date__c FROM Case WHERE Id = 'a0e000000000001'
```

You can also check how this one record appears for the user in question when viewed directly in the Web UI.